# Is the local time of the reflected SDE Markovian?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a stochastic differential equation: $X_0=x\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}
dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB^t+dL_t.
\end{equation}
where $L$ is nondecreasing and $B$ is a Brownian motion. Suppose $L$ is the unique process such that $X_t$ is reflected at some boundary $x^*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $X_t\geq x^*$ a.s. for all $t\geq 0$. This is known as the Skorokhod problem and $L$ (the local time of $X$ spent at $x^*$) has the expression
\begin{equation}
L_t=\sup_{0\leq s \leq t}\left(X_s-L_s\right)^-.
\end{equation}
My question is: Is the process $L$, $X$-Markovian?

My intuition is no. Because although $L$ `knows' to increase only when $X_t$ is at $x^*$, but as for how much it has to increase to reflect $X$, $L$ needs to know the dynamic of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L$ is not a Markov process on its own, but the pair $(L,X)$ is Markovian. This because of the additivity property
$$
L_{t+s} = L_t+L_s(\theta_t),
$$
in which $\theta_t$ stands for the time-shifted path $(X_{u+t})_{u\ge 0}$. From this (and the Markov property of $X$) it follows that the conditional distribution of $(L_{s+t},X_{s+t})_{s\ge 0}$, given the past of $X$ up to time $t$, depends only on $L_t$ and $X_t$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you know if $L_t\in\sigma(X_t)$ i.e. $L_t$ is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by $X_t$ for all $t\geq 0$?

Comment: No. $L_t$ accounts for *all* of the visiting of $X$ to $x$ up to time $t$, so it depends on more of the past-to-time-$t$ than just $X_t$.